# Não consigo usar um valor salvo no state do react

Tags: javascript, react

Criei um botão que recebe um **value**, ao clicar nele o value é armazenado no **state**, logo em seguida tento pegar esse valor do state mas **volta vazio**, o interessante é que no segundo clique no botão ele volta o valor do primeiro clique.

O valor do **target** não serve, pq preciso jogar o valor pro state para que outra função possa ser executada na sequência.

Como eu resolvo isso?

```
  eventToState = event => {
    this.setState({ buttonValue: event.target.value });
    console.log("teste", this.state.buttonValue);
  };

// SAÍDA
// teste "" 
// teste I'm the value of button element
```

**Código inteiro**
https://codesandbox.io/s/state-8fj2x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `setState` é assíncrono dentro de *event handlers*. Isso significa que o estado está sendo definido, mas não pode ser acessado através de `this.state` de forma síncrona. Há duas sessões da documentação que explicam esse fenômeno. Veja [aqui](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous) e [aqui](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-doesnt-react-update-thisstate-synchronously).

Você pode resolver esse problema passando um *callback* como segundo argumento para o `setState` ou chamando o método `this.test` passando o valor que você definiu no estado como argumento, já que isso tudo é feito na mesma função.

Então, passando o *callback* ao `setState`:

```
eventToState = (event) => {
  this.setState({ buttonValue: event.target.value }, () => {
    this.teste();
  });
};

teste = () => {
  console.log('Teste:', this.state.buttonValue);
};
```

Ou chamando o método `teste` passando como argumento o valor que você acabara de definir ao estado:

```
eventToState = (event) => {
  const newState = event.target.value;

  this.setState({ buttonValue: newState });
  this.teste(newState);
};

teste = (newState) => {
  console.log('Teste:', newState);
};
```

Para saber mais, consulte a [API do `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Answer (score 4):

Acontece que o método `setState` age de forma assíncrona (e não aceita `async await`, apenas `callback`). Então ele acaba mudando o valor de `buttonValue` após a chamada do `console.log`.

Para resolver isso, você pode usar um `callback` que será executado após o valor do estado ser alterado:

```
this.setState({ buttonValue: event.target.value }, () => {
    console.log("teste", this.state.buttonValue);
});
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques Desculpe, é um amigo meu ^^

Comment: @AugustoVasques tranquilo, você não sabia, e, aliás aqui não é uma "rede social pessoal" então valeu a dica sim!